# Truthtelling/Lying question (If B is lying then I'm lying)

Tags: logic

I'm stuck at a question about truthtelling/lying. Although similar problems have been posted I couldn't find a case similar to mine.

So a person is either a truthteller or a liar. Let's say we have two persons A and B. If I ask A: Are any of you telling the truth and A responds "If B is lying then I'm lying" How do I know who if they, individually, are lying or telling the truth. The way I see it there are two solutions, but I'm guessing one of my answers is wrong. I think that either they are both telling the truth or that A is lying and B is telling the truth.

I know that this can be set up with truth tables, but I'd like an explanation in words as to why and what I'm wrong about in my answer.

Comment: If A is a liar, the only way their statement can fail to pan out is if B is a liar, but A is a truth teller - contradiction...

Answer (score 1):

The last one is not true. If $B$ tells the truth, then the implication $A$ is stating is a true implication. Hence, $A$ told the truth. Do you understand?

Comment: From another perspective. If $A$ lies than his implication $(p\Rightarrow q)$ is wrong. The only possibility for this to be wrong is if $p$ is true and $q$ isn't. Hence, $A$ lying implies that $B$ is lying and $A$ tells the truth. This is an obvious contradiction :)

Comment: I'd like to look at it from the perspective where A is lying. So far I don't understand it. This isn't my strong suit. My brain is fried at doing these type of problems so you probably have to spell it out for me, even though it might seem obvious to you.

Comment: I'll try again but now in an interactive way. Do you know what it means if the statement $(p\Rightarrow q)$ is not true?

Comment: No I don't, but I'd love to know

Comment: So the implication is true in the following three possibilities. Notation (p,q): (1,1),(0,0),(0,1). Logic behind this reasoning: if p is true then q must be true because of the implication. If p is not true then the implication doesn't say anything, so q can be either. For example, consider: if it's raining, then I'll take the bus. This doesn't say anything about what I'll do when it is not raining but onlt when it is raining and in that case I'll take the bus. So, to stick to the point the only combination of the implication not being true is (1,0) (the only other option)

Comment: Okay, I'm with you so far. Just wondering.. If A is a liar (and therefore lies about the statement) does that mean that B will be telling the truth when A is lying?

Comment: No, the only way for the statement to be not true is that B is lying and A tells the truth.

Comment: If A is telling the truth and B is lying then A would have to be lying since B is lying which is a contradiction, right? I get that, I think. I just don't see why the statement still holds when A is lying and B is telling the truth.

Comment: Ok, so we're making step-by-step progress. So now, let's focus on the last point. You don't understand that the statement holds in case A is lying and B is telling the truth. The most simple explanation is found in the sense that the statement doesn't say anything about what A does in the case B is telling the truth. Maybe it is nice for you to read: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional